# av_frame_free crashes when using av_frame_get_buffer

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg

Whenever a allocate an AVFrame* using the folling code:

```
AVFrame *frame = av_frame_alloc();
frame->format = codec_context->pix_fmt;
frame->width = codec_context->width;
frame->height = codec_context->height;
if(av_frame_get_buffer(frame, 0) < 0){
    //handle error
}
```

And later try to free that frame* with `av_frame_free(&frame);`, my program crashes... however, if I allocate the frame using:

```
AVFrame *frame = av_frame_alloc();    
int num_bytes = av_image_get_buffer_size(codec_context->pix_fmt, codec_context->width, codec_context->height, 1);
buffer = (uint8_t*) av_malloc(num_bytes * sizeof(uint8_t));
av_image_fill_arrays(frame->data, frame->linesize, buffer, codec_context->pix_fmt, codec_context->width, codec_context->height, 1);
```

Then av_frame_free(&frame) does not crash. What am I doing wrong? What are the differences of allocating my frame these 2 ways? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Seems like you have typo here: `av_frame_get_buffer(rgb_frame, 0)`. Shouldn't it be `frame` here instead of `rgb_frame`

Comment: Sorry, I made the typo when asking the question, not on my original code. I corrected it now, the question remains though as asked.

Comment: I think problem is not here, you mentioned **"later try to free that `frame*` with `av_frame_free(&frame);`"**, perhaps you used `av_interleaved_write_frame` and then try to free it ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this error is during decoding though, so no av_interleaved_write_frame called... is there something similar during decoding that could be causing the difference between the two methods?